# How to test casting time?

Tags: c++, casting, runtime, compile-time

In an assignment, I have been asked to create my own static_cast and dynamic_cast using templates specialization.
How do I test that my static casts are really done compile-time and dynamic casts on run-time?

```
template<typename Dst, typename Src>
static Dst my_static_cast(Src src);

template<typename Dst, typename Src>
static Dst my_dynamic_cast(Src src);
```

Comment: Inspect the generated machine code?

Comment: A bit code would help, I guess.

Comment: For dynamic casts, you can prove it by writing code that compiles fine, but errors at run-time.  (e.g. for pointer types, dynamic_cast returns NULL if they are not compatible)

Comment: @DanielJour added function signatures, for what its worth... the implementation itself is nasty, and I don't want a specific answer to my code, but in general how to check casting times.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but consider this:

```
class D
{
public:
    virtual ~D(){}
};
class A : public D{};

class B{};
```

Now `dynamic_cast<B*>(new A())` compiles OK (and returns 0) but `static_cast<B*>(new A())` results in a compilation error. I'm almost sure you can SFINAE this to make an appropriate test.

Of course, this test assumes you only need to differentiate between 100% standard-compliant static_cast and 100% standard-compliant dynamic_cast. For detecting bugs in your implementation additional tests are needed.

EDIT:
You cannot fully test it automatically. Casts require runtime arguments and so they cannot be tested at compile time. And, at runtime, the only difference between compile-time calculated thing and runtime-calculated thing is performance. I wouldn't recommend testing by "well, runtime casts can't be that fast". It just isn't reliable.